# How completely remove user:admin filter in hue UI?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, oozie, hue

When I login to hue or refresh page I got filter with `user:admin` selected:

[image]

Is there a way to modify hue configs and remove this default filter? (It is very annoyuing to remove it on every page loading :'( )

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to your current logged in user. You may be able to use extensions like TamperMonkey to run Javascript after page load to clear the input box, but that'll cause unnecessary requests to the YARN server for more jobs than just the ones your user may have access to.